# Switching applications in react-router

Tags: react-router

I have a project, which will contain pre-frontoffice pages such as landing page, some info pages with pricing and other useful information and auth system. And the frontoffice application, which will be the main module. I think the best solution for that will be to separate two bundles.
I use react with react-router-dom and the first bundle.js I think will be only for landing, info and auth pages like:

```
    <Router>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
      <Route path="/login" component={Auth} />
      <Route path="/info" component={Info} />
    </Router>
```

And the second one I will use for main application like:

```
    <Router>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Portal} />
      <Route path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
      <Route path="/projects" component={Projects} />
      ...
    </Router>
```

My question is: how can I connect this two bundles?
I suppose I need to to use current `<a>` tag instead of `Link` component, which will pointing to another html-page with second bundle.
Is it correct way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make two separate applications but use common code between them. Use something like Webpack to share resources or Lerna to share packages.
Trying to create two applications in one tends to add complexity. Trying to get one class to do different things is hard once the application gets large. You end up with lots of checking code (if back-end then do this, show this, change this).

If you want to continue down this route then you need to think about Webpack lazy loading. however, in any case you should not use the same URL for two different features. For example the home page for the main app and the Portal.

```
/projects/
/admin/projects/
```

**Resources**

https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/

https://github.com/lerna/lerna

https://webpack.js.org/guides/lazy-loading/

Comment: Good day, Garry! Thank you for your reply. Your suggestions will be great in the future. At this point, I decided to separate not even bundles, but URLs indeed. I decided to use front bundle for landing, auth etc. on domain project.io and portal bundle on portal.project.io. Seems reasonable for me at this point. Good luck!